# Can I use scout with laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

Given Laravel scout was introcuced with laravel 5.3 can I use it with laravel 5.1?
The docs at https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scout doesn't state anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can include it in laravel 5.x as well , Using this blog

[**Blog Link**](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-search-functionality-with-laravel-scout-and-vue-js)

Also you can check Other Elastic Search plugin which are being used in laravel much before Scout

https://blog.madewithlove.be/post/integrating-elasticsearch-with-your-laravel-app/

https://github.com/cviebrock/laravel-elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

No It's not possible as `laravel/scout` required

```
illuminate/contracts: ~5.3
illuminate/database: ~5.3
illuminate/support: ~5.3
```

which is only available in laravel >=5.3